# Memory (Ram) overflow Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, spotify, ram

Hi all i'm trying to make a login view like spotify.
https://github.com/chenjunpu/SpotifyLoginVideo 
i use this example.

My problem is that when i try to go to login page the ram that it use is the same with the video view (plus 30mb)

I tried this on the buttons function but nothing changed

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Any ideas how can i stop the view drain my ram?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Download code existing on https://github.com/chenjunpu/SpotifyLoginVideo  I see when we go to login the application keeps running over 100Mbs ram.

adding this code to WelcomeViewController

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    self.videoView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.videoView = UIView()
}
```

problem solved but we need to setup all over again on viewWillAppear so

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.viewDidLoad()
}
```

this works for me regards